# the script is not terminated after pressing ctrl + c

Tags: bash

I have a select menu with 4 options. I want that in case of pressing ctrl + c, remove some files before terminating the program. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

ctrl_c() {
     test -f directory/file.txt && rm directory/file.txt
}

trap ctrl_c INT

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
while true; do
    clear
    options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Exit")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
        case $opt in
            "Option 1")
                echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
                break
                ;;
            "Option 2")
                echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
                break
                ;;
            "Option 3")
                echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
                break
                ;;
            "Exit")
                break 2
                ;;
            *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
        esac
    done
read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..."
done
```

but when I run this code and press ctrl + c, nothing happens and the program is not terminated, just `^c` is typed. What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> sends the SIGINT signal, but you are capturing that and assigning it to your `ctrl_c` function:

```
trap ctrl_c INT
```

So when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, your script will execute the function instead of quitting. If that's not what you want, remove the `trap` command.

If your objective is to run the `ctrl_c` function and then exit, you need to tell your script to exit explicitly:

```
ctrl_c() {
     test -f directory/file.txt && rm directory/file.txt
     exit
}
```

When you trap a signal, it is up to you to implement what you want your program to do in response to that signal.

This will however not work as expected unless the `posix` shell option is active (`set -o posix`) as signals are not delivered while a command is actively executing (see "[Bash ignoring SIGINT trap when 'select' loop is running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513466/bash-ignoring-sigint-trap-when-select-loop-is-running)").

This means that you may want to use `set -o posix` before calling `select` (and then possibly `set +o posix` afterwards).

Comment: Hi folks. Please don't use comments for discussion like this. I have moved this to [a chat room instead](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106550/discussion-on-answer-by-terdon-the-script-is-not-terminated-after-pressing-ctrl). @pablo